# Can pins (breadboard friendly) be added to non-drilled pads?

Tags: pcb, soldering, breadboard, prototyping

Some PCBA's have pads along the edge, where I believe some kind of headers could be soldered (or may be not), but don't have the pads drilled. I guess manufacturers save a little cost on drilling, and is not a problem when these are breakout boards used in production settings. To turn them into something that is breadboard friendly, apart from drilling holes, is there any alternative option -- s.a. a novel way of soldering pins ?

PS> Aversion to drilling is that these are FR4 boards, and I do not have drill-press or access to one.

Comment: Why not add a picture?  You maybe talking about board edge connectors (think of boards that go into your PC)

Comment: Edge connectors? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:44EdgeConnector.jpg

Comment: @rawbrawb, good idea. Unfortunately, I don't have a camera handy, and didn't find a good image to post so far.

Comment: starblue, not really. @ThePhoton 's answer below is close to what I need, although in my case the pads are not the small test-pads, but a full array of header pads (single row). Handsoldering a strip connector is the expected usage style (I believe), but I'd like to mount it on a breadboard to experiment.

Comment: Round or rectangular? What's the spacing between pads?

Comment: @ThePhoton all round, barring one, which is rectangular, i.e. you are asking about the shape of the pads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No holes drilled makes me think SMT.

Are these what you're looking for?

[image]

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/0015916102/WM3699TR-ND/2421395

Comment: Absolutely. Although, in my case the PCBA has a single row (like berg-strip) of these pads, and the design of the header seems to suggest mechanical robustness based on 2 rows. Are you aware of a single row header as well ? Searching on Digikey didn't yield a SMT variant.

Comment: Actually, found a good reference and another potential solution here, although soldering seems to be a bit of a task. https://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=33498

Comment: single row versions of this header i have seen look like this:  http://media.digikey.com/photos/Sullins%20Photos/SMH100-LPSE-S15-SD-BK.JPG This is a top view of the part. the legs to solder to alternate back and forth on which way they point. this probably doesnt help you if they are all in a line on your PCB, though.

Answer (score 2):

If the pads in question are simply small circles with solder mask removed from over them, they're probably test points for use with a pogo-pin test fixture.

[image]

In general, you shouldn't drill through them unless this is a one or two-layer board, or you for some other reason know there's no copper connected to other nets on any of the inner layers beneath these pads.

(Image shamelessly stolen from [Dictionary of Terms for Electronic Engineering](http://www.interfacebus.com/Dictionary-of-PWB-Terms.html))

Comment: Quite close, but not exactly. In my case, I am sure that these are not test pads, but a linear row of pads on which "some kind of header pins" could be soldered.

Comment: If you can post a picture in your question, we'd have a much better chance of giving you a useful answer.